# Reading integer from file end with ``Missing format for FORMATTED data transfer done``

Tags: io, format, fortran

I'm updating a Fortran program for my needs. The program compiles using `f95` and `gcc` version 4.1.2 (I know it is old, but I can't update it). I want to read parameters from a file and I try this via

```
      inquire (file="resLast", exist=resExist)
      if (readStart.eq.1.and.resExist) then
         open (unit=18,file='resLast', status='old', action='read')
         read (18) startConf
         read (18) avlength, stdlength, avenergy
         read (18) i,h2(1)
         read (18) i,h2(2)
         read (18) i,h2(4)
         read (18) i,h2(5)
         read (18) i,h2(8)
         read (18) i,h2(9)
         read (18) i,h2(13)
         read (18) i,h2(16)
         read (18) i,h2(17)
         read (18) i,h2(18)
         read (18) i,h2(20)
         read (18) i,h2(25)
         read (18) i,h2(32)
         close (18)
      else
         startConf = 0
         do i=1,32
            h2(i)=0
            comh2(i)=0
         enddo
         avlength=0d0
         stdlength=0d0
         avenergy=0d0
      endif
```

The input file looks like

```
           0
   196.090732114834        38451.5752213317        53.4452884569457     
           1  9.188750409521163E-004
           2  4.548226133920252E-004
           4  8.704101492185146E-005
           5  2.175445697503164E-004
           8  4.992044341634028E-005
           9  2.108949411194772E-005
          13  4.304789035813883E-005
          16  4.693072696682066E-005
          17  8.976260141935199E-005
          18  2.737747854553163E-005
          20  5.637826689053327E-005
          25  3.860405195155181E-005
          32  3.193027441739105E-005
```

When I try to run this I get an error

```
Fortran runtime error: Missing format for FORMATTED data transfer
done
```

Which points to the first `read` line. The `startConf variable, as well as`i`` is an integer. The rest of the variables are double precision.

I've used this method to read data into integers previously (even in the same code) without problem, where is my current fault?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you do not specify it explicitely, your `open` statement assumes a `formatted` (text) file. When reading from a text file, you have to provide a format as well:

```
read(18, *) i1
```

Alternatively, if your file is `unformatted` (binary), open your file accordingly:

```
 open (unit=18, file='resLast', status='old', action='read', form='unformatted')
```

Comment: To be exact, your example read is "list-directed I/O".  It will work, and its a lot easier than providing formats.

Answer (score 0):

read(18,*)is a better choice. you can try this.